# Lower reputation required to write tag wiki on private beta SE sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, tag-wiki, private-beta

Can the required reputation (currently 2000) be lowered for the tag wiki editing?

Right now, it will take about 10 days for the first user to get to the reputation required for editing, and then only if they have a score of 100 in the tag they want to edit.

Being able to build the tag wikis right now, in the private beta, will help users understand the terminology in use once we move to public beta.<sup>1</sup> Presumably the users in the private beta will be fairly well-versed in the topic, and having this information prepared now will make it easier as we move up in popularity.

<sup>1</sup> Related: [What the hell is a Presta Tube? - or: SE sites need a glossary for foreigners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62296/what-the-hell-is-a-presta-tube-or-se-sites-need-a-glossary-for-foreigners)

Comment: It appears to be 1000 on the SE sites

Comment: @Michael Interesting, you seem to be partially right... on [UI](http://ui.stackexchange.com) and [DIY](http://diy.stackexchange.com), it's 1000 (which are both in public beta), but on [Bicycles](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com) it's 2000 (which is in private beta). Maybe the private beta needs to be adjusted too?

Comment: FWIW, we've just entered public beta on RPG and there are only three of us who can edit tag wikis at all; subjectively this feels like too few but I offer it as a data point more than anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed, any registered user can now submit edits to tag wikis