# Glossary / dictionary for SE sites

Tags: feature-request, area-51, internationalization

Unlike in programming where English is the undisputed *Lingua Franca* - the whole working vocabulary of the profession is English  - many of the new Stack Exchange sites will be harder to use for non-native English speakers because of a lot of domain specific vocabulary.

To remedy this,  introducing an illustrated, multi-language glossary for each SE site would help a lot. Many sites have started this on their own already - see discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62296/what-the-hell-is-a-presta-tube-or-se-sites-need-a-glossary-for-foreigners) - but I think this needs a more organized approach.

Here's a suggestion.
[image]
[image]

## 1. **Defining terms for the glossary**

For each term needing definition, create a question on the site. Title it "Glossary:" and add the term in question.
The question gets the `glossary` tag. That tag becomes a moderator/administrator tag like `status-*` on Meta.
[image]

[image]

## 2. **User input**

Let users answer the glossary question following two defined formats:

**For translations:**

> - Language/locale (`xx-YY`, e.g. `en-US`, `en-GB`, `fr-FR`)
> - Translation
> - Wikipedia link

one translation per answer.

**For images:**

> - The word "Image" in the first line
> - Uploaded image
> - Copyright status (an issue in itself)

[image]

## 3. **Output**

Fetch the **highest-voted translations for each glossary term and language**, and the **highest-voted image for each**, and auto-generate a nice-looking, illustrated glossary. (Or rather, dictionary?)

Something roughly along the lines of:

[image]

(It would have to be cleaned somewhat and restructured to suit longer words, more languages, missing translations and so on.)
The user's browser language version would always be highlighted in yellow.
[image]
[image]

## 4. **Linking to glossary terms in questions**

If glossary terms are used in a question or one of its answers, let the space to the right, below the "Related" section, show a linked list of glossary terms.

The list items will simply link to each glossary question:

> **Terms used on this page:**
>
> - Mincing
> - Sautéed
> - Angelica

if the user's browser language is set to a non-english language, show the translation for that language automatically (in this example, German):

> **Terms used on this page:**
>
> - Mincing (Hacken)
> - Sautéed (Garen)
> - Angelica (Brustwurz)

that way, quick access to translations is guaranteed, but with a minimum of obtrusiveness and user preference settings.

[image]

Comment: This kinda seems like busywork, given how well Google works for this sort of thing most of the time. But it would be cool...

Comment: @Shog don't underestimate the effort of looking up 3-4 words while reading through a question. I felt totally lost on the bicycling site for this reason...

Comment: Won't most of these terms have tags and so be defined in tag wikis?

Comment: @Simon not always. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62296/what-the-hell-is-a-presta-tube-or-se-sites-need-a-glossary-for-foreigners/62300#62300

Comment: It sounds like a lot of effort, but given how much work is going into glossary "questions" on various sites (community wiki, for the most part) it seems like a useful extension. As it is new users have to realise there is a glossary then find it and manually look stuff up every time. If it can be auto-magic'd somehow that would be very handy. Note that many times it's a term rather than a single word "Schrader valve" or "chain tool", where picking one or both words by themselves is not as useful. That bit will be fun to code :)