# Is there a way to label acronyms in a miniature form?

Tags: feature-request

I usually link to the article, often a Wikipedia article, but sometimes I just want a way to name the acronym, without linking to the article. Is there correct code I would use so when you mouse over, or click it shows the acronym, but something that is not confused with a broken link?

An added bonus would be if the system could automatically label this sort of thing.

[Example Question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10022/help-with-ssl-teaching-material) using **Compsci** (Computer Science)

Comment: I think the feature request is here: [Defining a term with markdown or HTML](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85165/defining-a-term-with-markdown-or-html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is very similar to the request to add support for the `<abbr>` or `<acronym>` tags, which [was requested three years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13453/134300) but never added. I'd also like to see something like this supported.

---

FYI, you can add a `title` attribute to your links, so that users who hover over them for a couple of seconds can see the unabbreviated form. Using HTML:

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer" title="Secure Sockets Layer" >SSL</a>
```

> [SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer)

Using Markdown ([see FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-links)):

```
You need to foo that bar over [SSL][ssl]!

  [ssl]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer
         "Secure Sockets Layer"
```

> You need to foo that bar over [SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer)!

Comment: Looks like a great idea to me! All that is needed is an alternate CSS. I like [the idea of dashed lines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85165/defining-a-term-with-markdown-or-html).

Comment: Just FYI: `<acronym>` was deprecated in HTML 4.01 and is no longer supported in HTML 5. Only `<abbr>` is allowed now.

Comment: When abusing links, then there's no need for HTML; see [Advanced Links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-links) in the Markdown help.